# Tamaño en bytes de un número

Tags: python

Estoy buscando un método o función en Python que retorne el tamaño en bytes de un número o caracter, sabiendo que un `1 byte = 8 bits`.

Se que existe la función `sys.sizeof()` pero no me devuelve la salida que yo espero.

Por ejemplo:
El número `10` ocupa `1byte` dado que el número `10` se encuentra dentro del rango de la tabla **ASCII** (que el número máximo en `1byte es 256` si no estoy mal).
Una letra/caracter cualquiera también ocupa `1byte` porque la contiene la tabla ASCII

Así mismo el número `1000` ocupa `2bytes` ya que se encuentra fuera del rango y se calcularía con `2**10` que es `1024` pero el 10 ya no se encuentra dentro del primer byte.

Comment: Esta pregunta no está muy clara: ¿qué devuelve `sys.sizeof()`?¿por qué no es la salida que esperas?¿cuál es la salida que esperas?¿a qué te refieres con "_el 10 ya no se encuentra dentro del primer byte_"?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro porque cuando hago el `sys.sizeof(10)` me devuelve 28,   pero ese no es el tamaño que expliqué arriba, deberia ser 1, ya que es un byte. Ahora mirando esa salida puede ser que arroje es el tamaño de un tipo entero o float

Comment: eso te devolverá el tamaño de un int (+ un overhead para el objeto). Quizás podrías probar algo como [`bit_length`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length), y hacerle un módulo 8 (+1) para encontrar el mínimo número de bytes.

Comment: perfecto,  muchas gracias alvaro!